# Dynamic color change in ASP.NET Radio Button using CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net, dynamic

I managed to reach the desired results using a standard HTML Form but when I started modifying the layout to use ASP.NET web controls instead... I can't seem to get the same effect to happen. The original CSS/HTML I used is as follows:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    div.sqgrp1 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 123px;
                height: 40px;
                width: 40px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-color: #178e62;
                background-color: #6ec3a1;
                padding-left:0px; 
                padding-top:0px; 
                padding-bottom:0px; 
                padding-right:0px;
                border-radius:10px;
            }
            input[type="radio"] {
                display: none;
            }
                input[type="radio"] + label span {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 40px;
                    height: 40px;
                    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    border-radius:10px;
                    background-color:red;
                    background-size:0px;
                    background:black;
                    opacity:0;
                               }
                input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
                    opacity: 0.6;
                    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body><form id="phq9" name="phq9" action="process.aspx" method="post" runat="server">
    <div class="sqgrp1" style="left: 660px;">
                 <input type="radio"id="Q1A1" value="1" name="Q1" /><label for="Q1A1" ><span></span></label>
                    </div>
            <div class="sqgrp1" style="left: 730px;">
                <input type="radio"id="Q1A2" value="2" name="Q1" /><label for="Q1A2"><span></span></label>
        </div>
            <div class="sqgrp1" style="left: 800px;">
                <input type="radio"id="Q1A3" value="3" name="Q1" /><label for="Q1A3"><span></span></label>
        </div>    
            <div class="sqgrp1" style="left: 870px;">
                <input type="radio"id="Q1A4" value="4" name="Q1" /><label for="Q1A4"><span></span></label>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried several ways to make the same effect happen with ASP.NET controls but none of them worked so I reverted back to the regular HTML controls.

Comment: You need to include the HTML (preferably the original, and also the version using ASP.NET controls) and then explain which part isn't working. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited post to include enough information for the original format, however I didn't keep all my efforts to use ASP.NET so don't have an example of that. Really all I did was attempt to change input type="radio" to asp:radiobutton runat="server" and then modify the <style> tag to represent the changes made in the original html tags... but it never worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue I was having.  Setting up all the controls as asp was fine but making the label asp:label was resulting in errors with the CSS.  By leaving the label tag as normal html the CSS works exactly the same, even with the radio buttons as `<asp:radiobutton runat="server">`.